# Halting due to unrecoverable I/O error while handling produce request: (kafka.server.KafkaApis)

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I am running kafka with some big problems of stability. First let me explain what I have and how Id o have have configure it.

I have 3 zookeeper (3.4.6) in three separate hosts (not vm).

I have 3 kafka (0.8.1) with the following configuration (all of them have the same configuration):

```
Cores: 12
RAM: 64 GB
SDD: 400 GB
OS: Ubuntu minimal 64 bits.
```

Each kafka have the same properties:

```
broker.id=1
port=9091
host.name=esp-kf1
num.network.threads=8
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
num.partitions=100
log.flush.interval.messages=10000
log.retention.hours=12
log.segment.bytes=536870912
log.retention.check.interval.ms=60000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181
default.replication.factor=2
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=1000000
```

Each of the 3 kafka have its own broker id, port and hostname.

Even if I have a default partitions of 100, what I really do is to create the topics manually in order to configure them depending on what are they going to be used for:

```
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 100 -config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_IN_SAVED
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 120 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_MAP_FOUND
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 400 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_IN_POSITIONS
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 400 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_IN_PRICES
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 2000 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_IN_OFFERS
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 600 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_IN
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 10 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic PLATFORM_DATA_SAVED
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 10 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_MAPPED
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 10 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic TARGET_DATA_UPDATED
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 10 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic TARGET_DATA_CREATED
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper esp-zk1:2181,esp-zk2:2181,esp-zk3:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partition 10 --config retention.ms=720 --config cleanup.policy=delete --topic DATA_NOT_MAPPED
```

So I have 11 topics and a total of 3670 partitions between the eleven topics.

As for the kafka-server-start.sh I have added export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx16G -Xms16G" (the same happens with 1G, 2G and 4G).

The stack trace I get after a while in each of them is:

```
[2015-04-13 13:16:46,171] WARN Newly rolled segment file 00000000000000001605.log already exists; deleting it first (kafka.log.Log)
[2015-04-13 13:16:46,171] WARN Newly rolled segment file 00000000000000001605.index already exists; deleting it first (kafka.log.Log)
[2015-04-13 13:16:46,272] FATAL [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-3], Disk error while replicating data. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
kafka.common.KafkaStorageException: I/O exception in append to log 'DATA_IN_OFFERS-1130'
    at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:286)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.processPartitionData(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:52)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$processFetchRequest$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:130)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$processFetchRequest$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:178)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:347)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:347)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:347)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$processFetchRequest$1.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:111)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$processFetchRequest$1.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:111)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$processFetchRequest$1.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:111)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:110)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:88)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:888)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:286)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$resize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:276)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.resize(OffsetIndex.scala:276)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply$mcV$sp(OffsetIndex.scala:265)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:265)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$trimToValidSize$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:265)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)
    at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.trimToValidSize(OffsetIndex.scala:264)
    at kafka.log.Log.roll(Log.scala:472)
    at kafka.log.Log.maybeRoll(Log.scala:448)
    at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:246)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:885)
    ... 26 more
```

After several of this (from one 1 to n) the kafka stops working.

The thing is that I do not know whats really happening and way its happening this.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Frank

Comment: Have you investigated the error message in your logs above:

"[2015-04-13 13:16:46,272] FATAL [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-3], Disk error while replicating data. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
kafka.common.KafkaStorageException: I/O exception in append to log 'DATA_IN_OFFERS-1130'"

Is your hard disk out of space, is it damaged, etc.?

Comment: Yes the solution was to "match" the producer and consumer maximum number of bytes per message, you should not produce bigger message than those that you can consumer.

message.max.bytes -->   The maximum size of a message that the server can receive. It is important that this property be in sync with the maximum fetch size your consumers use or else an unruly producer will be able to publish messages too large for consumers to consume.

Comment: Great to hear you found the problem in the configuration.  FYI:  If you happen to run Kafka's MirrorMaker tool you must similar configure MirrorMaker's `fetch.message.max.bytes` (which should match the brokers' fetch size setting).